# werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: I am not able to figure why I am getting this error

Tags: python, flask

I am requesting a file to be uploaded but I get a keyerror even though I have name="imagefile" in my form.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])


@app.route('/', methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    imagefile = request.files['imagefile']
    image_path = "./images/"+imagefile.filename
    imagefile.save(image_path)

    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=3000, debug=True)


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tutorial</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Image Classifer</h1>

        <form class="p-3 text-center" action='/', method=""post enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            <input class="form-control" type="file" name='imagefile' >
            <input class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit" value="Predict Image" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am not sure why it is not detecting imagefile... Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't correctly setting your `GET` and `POST` methods for your single route. In addition to this, you also need some logic on your route to handle the POST request from your form.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def predict():
    if request.method == "POST":
        imagefile = request.files['imagefile']
        image_path = "./images/" + imagefile.filename
        imagefile.save(image_path)

    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=3000, debug=True)
```

I also noticed that you have a typo in your form `method` attribute.

```html
<form class="p-3 text-center" action='/' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```